# Showing a Delayed Webcam Image

Tags: macos, mac, webcam

I have a Logitech USB webcam, and need to display the image from it on a second monitor, delayed roughly 15 seconds ish. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! "If there was a way to do this on windows, please mention it too." Questions about Windows are off-topic for this site, so I removed that part of your question. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious, what use case do you have for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) in Terminal:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC qtcapture://
```

Ask on their forums. If there isn't an option to delay the direct display, you can always "stream" it to another VLC process and let it buffer for 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In code? Read the webcam data stream into a buffer, then add a timer for 15 seconds then at the end of the timer read the buffer out to a video renderer.

Comment: Sorry, I know next to nothing about cocoa programming and really couldn't program something like this.